# animation starting at specific time

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to use animation in my app, but it shoudn't start from beggining, but from time that I set, hot to achieve that? My code working from beggining of animation:

```
ImageView someImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someImage);
Animation someAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.someAnimation);
someImage.startAnimation(someAnimation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set time using `Animation.setStartTime()`, then assign the animation to the View with `View.setAnimation()`.

Check developer.android site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html